# how to fetch the selected value of drop down list on page refresh in drop down itself

Tags: jsp

i have written following code in jsp page

```
<%
 String name2 = request.getParameter( "value" );
 session.setAttribute( "theName", name2 );
%>
```

and in body of jsp page

```
<%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>
```

so i am able to see the values of selected dropdown on page refresh in jsp page but unable to get the same value in dropdwon list .I have written the code in single jsp page and after refresh also same jsp page is being releoaded.The problem i am facing is on page refresh value is not being fetched in dropdown where as same value i am able to see in page body.

Comment: Please explain your question a bit further. What are you trying to achieve? What dropdown list? Thanks!

Comment: i am having 2 drop down list lob and group .2nd drop down(group) is populated based on 1st dropdown list(lob).so while selecting 1st dropdown(lob) page is getting refreshed i am able to see the values in 2nd dropdwon(group) but after page is refreshed 1st drop down value(lob) is not getting restored.

Comment: How are you filling the dropdown lists? Post that part if you can, please. Also do you have the parameter `value` provided everytime? Are there any errors in your log?

Comment: <%
 LOBAction action=new LOBAction();
 List<MLOBConfig> LOBList = new ArrayList<MLOBConfig>();
 LOBList = action.getLOBDetails();
 String name;
 
 //login.saveData();
%>

Comment: <option value= "" selected="true">--select--</option>
       
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  <%
                   for (int i = 0; i < LOBList.size(); i++) {
                     name = LOBList.get(i).getlob_Name();
                  %>
                 <option value="<%=name%>" > <%= name %> </option> 
                  
                  
                <%   }
                  %>